# ya2yaml vs. params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

I'm working with Rails 3 and ya2yaml, and I'm having an encoding issue trying to convert a params hash to yaml. The keys for the params hash are being stored as **ASCII-8BIT** and the values are being stored as **UTF-8**. This creates a problem, since ya2yaml doesn't like ASCII, and if you try to generate yaml from an ASCII string using ya2yaml, you get this:

```
--- 
? !binary |
    b25l

: "some_value"
```

Instead of this:

```
--- 
someKey : "some_value"
```

Blech. Does anyone know how to bypass this in ya2yaml, or force a hash's keys and values to use the same encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just writing a method that duplicated the params hash and encoded the keys and values in UTF-8:

```
  def utf8_hash(some_hash) # convert hash key & values to utf-8 for proper translation
    new_hash = Hash.new
    some_hash.each do |key, value|
      new_hash[key.to_s.encode(Encoding::UTF_8)] = value.to_s.encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
    end    
    new_hash
  end

  utf8_hash(params).ya2yaml
```